# SVR without support vectors is not possible?

Tags: regression, modeling, svm

I have a doubt regarding the response surface created by Support Vector Regression model. Please let me know if my understanding is sound.

In my query below, I would be referring to equations based on this paper https://alex.smola.org/papers/2003/SmoSch03b.pdf.

An SVR model can be completely defined by the support vectors (sample points which lie on or outside the epsilon-margin). What if my data set has points such that all points can satisfy the epsilon constraints (Eq. 2) with a strict inequality (<). For instance, let us assume the following example. My true response-generating function is y=2x+4, with some random noise. The black solid line in the figure is the true response profile, while the * represent the data points. Let's assume epsilon to be 0.2, which gives us the epsilon-tube marked by red dashed lines in the figure.
[image]

Applying SVR to the data points, ideally one would expect any ML algorithm to yield the true response-generating function or a profile that resembles it the most. But if SVR profile matches with the true profile, there are no support vectors (as all points lie strictly within the epsilon tube). This would yield a constant SVR prediction based on Eq. 11 which is definitely not true. In order to get an appropriate SVR profile, it would need to have at least 1 support vector (i.e. at least 1 sample point on the upper or lower boundary of the epsilon margin).

My question is : Does SVR necessarily need to have at least 1 support vector to build an appropriate predictive model? If yes, for such a case, how does SVR determine which margin (upper or lower) has the support vectors -  as we can shift the upper margin downwards to have support vectors, or we can shift the lower margin upwards, and have all points satisfying the constraints in Eq. 2, and both cases can yield the same (flattest possible) slope but with different intercepts.